# Finding last occurrence of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following type of table in html, which is generated dynamically by php :

```
<tr><td>Kiss the Girls</td><td>2016-01-01</td></tr>
<tr><td>Kiss the Girls</td><td>2016-02-05</td></tr>
<tr><td>Along Came a Spider</td><td>2016-01-07</td></tr>
<tr><td>Along Came a Spider</td><td>2016-01-22</td></tr>
<tr><td>Along Came a Spider</td><td>2016-03-31</td></tr>
```

I would like to be able to have a dynamic display filter that would allow the user to click a box and hide all but the latest version of the manuscript. So it might look like :

```
<tr><td>Kiss the Girls</td><td>2016-02-05</td></tr>
<tr><td>Along Came a Spider</td><td>2016-03-31</td></tr>
```

At this point none of the `<tr>` or `<td>` tags have an id or a class, but I could easily add a class to the first column (e.g., `<td class='bookTitle'>`). There is only one table on the page and php sorts it by date already. I'm open to jQuery or native JavaScript, though I would think this would be easier with jQuery. Seems like it could be done by just grabbing the last row before it changes names, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `'Seems like it could be done by just grabbing the last row before it changes names'`, this is what I've come out with:

```
var rows = $("table tr");
if(rows.length > 0){
  var last = $(rows[0]).find('td')[0].innerText;
  for(var i=1; i<rows.length; i++){
     var row = $(rows[i]);
     var text = row.find('td')[0].innerText;
     if(text === last){
        $(rows[i-1]).hide();
     }
     last = text;
  }
}
```

See the Pen [Finding last occurrence of text](http://codepen.io/tanhauhau/pen/yOQxRa/) by Tan Li Hau ([@tanhauhau](http://codepen.io/tanhauhau)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Comment: Worked perfectly... especially after I added a little "  `if ($(this).is(':checked')) { ... } else {    $("tr").show(); }` logic

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `tr` and store in key value pair where key as `td` content and value as object, after get the objects from it.

```js
var a = {}; // object for storing dom element object

$('table tr').each(function() {
  a[$('td:first', this).text().trim()] = this; // update the dom element object based on the column
});

var $res = $($.map(a, function(v) {
  return v; // get objects and convert to jQuery object
}));

console.log($res);

$res.css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Kiss the Girls</td>
    <td>2016-01-01</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kiss the Girls</td>
    <td>2016-02-05</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Along Came a Spider</td>
    <td>2016-01-07</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Along Came a Spider</td>
    <td>2016-01-22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Along Came a Spider</td>
    <td>2016-03-31</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**FYI :** If you want to maintain the order then the value with index and object array and set order based on that

Comment: Object.keys wasn’t implemented in Internet Explorer until version 9, use instead $.map(obj,func());

Comment: It took a while to understand it all. But, this was genius! Succint beauty !! Thanks.

Comment: @SarathChandra : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate in reverse and remove everything you've seen before as you go:

```js
function filterPreviousVersions ( ) {
    var seen = {};
    $( $('tr').get( ).reverse( ) ).each( function ( ) {
        var text = $( 'td', this ).first( ).text();
        if ( seen[ text ] )
            $( this ).remove();
        seen[ text ] = true;
    } );
}

filterPreviousVersions();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Kiss the Girls</td>
    <td>2016-01-01</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kiss the Girls</td>
    <td>2016-02-05</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Along Came a Spider</td>
    <td>2016-01-07</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Along Came a Spider</td>
    <td>2016-01-22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Along Came a Spider</td>
    <td>2016-03-31</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add ids in increasing order as you add the rows,

You may use this :

```js
var valArray = [];
$('.maindiv').each(function() {
  valArray.push(parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10));
})
valArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
})

alert("Last row : " + document.getElementById(valArray[valArray.length - 1]).innerHTML); // highest`
alert("Second last : " +  document.getElementById(valArray[valArray.length - 2]).innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="2" class="maindiv">Contents in row 2</div>
<div id="5" class="maindiv">Contents in row 5</div>
<div id="3" class="maindiv">Contents in row 3</div>
<div id="1" class="maindiv">Contents in row 1</div>
<div class="main">Contents in test row</div>
<div id="4" class="maindiv">Contents in row 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To put it all together:

**Succint**: (May have some performance impact for large tables with many duplicate values)

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  $("tr :contains('" + $('td', this).first().html() + "')").last()
   .parent().css('color', 'red'); 
});
```

Explanation for the succint version:-

```
$('tr').each(function(){ // for each row of the table
  $("tr                    // find a child inside a tr 
     :contains('"          // that contains the text
    +  $('td', this)         // present within a td of the row (in line 1) 
      .first().html()        // at the beginning  
    + "')")               // Using string concat to pass variable to `contains` selector)  
    .last()               // at the end (last occurence of text)
   .parent()              // invoke `parent()` to select whole row
   .css('color', 'red');  // apply css to identify the desired row.
});
```

**Verbose**: (Using `Set` of ECMAScript6 or `$.unique()` to remove duplicates from the full list of names. This way, when the `forEach` loop at the end of the code runs, it'll iterate only one per name.)

```
var uniqueNames = []; 
$('tr').each(function(){
  uniqueNames.push($('td', this).first().html());  
});  // this will return the list of names from the table

// Remove duplicates from the list of names
uniqueNames = new Set(uniqueNames); // OR: uniqueNames = $.unique(uniqueNames);
uniqueNames.forEach(function(el){
  $("tr :contains('" + el + "')").last().parent().css('color', 'red');
});
```